# Do a COUNT and a SUM in the same query for the same WHERE claus

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table which has this row amongst others `totalprice`

I'm doing the WHERE clause based on a status field and a date between X and X

I want to do a count of the orders between the date and also get the SUM of totalprice for those orders.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM `orders` 
WHERE `processed` IN (2,3,4,5) 
AND `date` BETWEEN %s AND %s", $start_timestamp, $end_timestamp
```

Code runs in Wordpress hence the %s
I just can't figure out how to get the `SUM(totalprice)` working in that same query to avoid doing a separate one

Comment: Just add another select value? `SELECT count(*) as cnt, sum(totalPrice) as SumTotalPrice FROM ...`

Comment: Next will be `AVG()` and then things get **really** crazy.

Answer (score 0):

Your query should simply add the term for which you're needing:

```
"SELECT COUNT(*), SUM(totalPrice) FROM 'orders' WHERE 'processed' IN (2,3,4,5) AND 'date' BETWEEN %s AND %s", $start_timestamp, $end_timestamp
```

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you select two columns - one that gives the count, the other that gives the sum. You don't need two queries for that *even if there are separate conditions for calcuating count and sum.*

> Oh, and I have to do this

Count of Orders and the Sum of total price (the good version)

```
select count(*), sum(totalprice) from orders where processed in (2,3,4,5) 
and date between start_timestamp and end_timestamp;
```

Count of Orders and the Sum of total price (the bad version)

```
select count(case when date between start_timestamp and end_timestamp 
then 'valid' else null end) count_of_orders,
sum(case when date between start_timestamp and end_timestamp 
then totalprice else 0 end) sum_of_total_price;
```

Count of Orders and Sum of the total price (day-wise)

```
select date(date), count(*), sum(totalprice) from orders 
where processed in (2,3,4,5) 
and date between start_timestamp and end_timestamp group by date(date);
```

I can't emphasize this enough

> Never use *keywords* as column names - for example, date shouldn't be the name of a column ever.

When you have separate conditions for count and sum

```
select date(date), count(case when totalprice > 100 then 'valid' else null end), 
sum(totalprice) from orders where processed in (2,3,4,5) 
and date between start_timestamp and end_timestamp group by date(date);
```

You can do all kinds of things.